# Sublime Build 3126 : How to highlight all the line that contains my found phrase after searching?

Tags: search, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, highlight, highlighting

I have an original version of Sublime Build 3126. Please, I need to learn the following if possible.

Basically, when I search for a term and click on the found line from the results window, I would like the Sublime editor to highlight the whole line that contains my term. At the moment, every time I click on the search result entries, I need to look again through the page for the line that contains the term. The Sublime editor is only highlighting the line number which is very hard to notice.

Ideally speaking, the whole line that contains the term might be highlighted and the term itself must be boxed/highlighted in a different way for instant identification.

If anyone knows how to adjust that to make it clear and easy to identify the found terms, it would be greatly appreciated.

I am using the Ubuntu version of Sublime.

Comment: have you considered setting `"highlight_line": true,` in your User preferences?

Comment: +1 : That's amazing! I have just tried it and it looks way much better now. Thank you so much. Do you know if there is a way to "bold" or highlight the current found phrase or term?

When you search for a term on a page, you find that Sublime is highlighting and boxing up the term for you. This is extremely helpful. However, when I click the line from the search results panel, the found term is never highlighted or boxed up in a border. Is there any hack to that?